# Why should the output of this C code be "no"?

Tags: c, comparison-operators, unsigned-integer

I came across this question.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    // your code goes here
    unsigned int i = 23;
    signed char c = -23;

    if (i > c)
        printf("yes");
    else
        printf("no");

    return 0;
}
```

I am unable to understand why the output of this code is `no`.

Can someone help me in understanding how the comparison operator works when comparison is done between `int` and `char` in C ?

Comment: Read about [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement). and about [the implicit conversions in C](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion) (especially about [the arithmetic conversions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Usual_arithmetic_conversions)).

Comment: The canonical source is the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) (that's the N1570 draft). See 6.3.1.1 for the *integer promotions* (which convert the `signed char` value to `int`), and 6.3.1.8 for the *usual arithmetic conversions* (which convert both operands to a common type, `unsigned int`, before performing the comparison).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are comparing an `unsigned int` to a `signed char`.  The semantics of this kind of comparison are counter-intuitive: most binary operations involving `signed` and `unsigned` operands are performed on unsigned operands, after converting the signed value to unsigned (if both operands have the same size after promotion).  Here are the steps:

- The `signed char` value is promoted to an `int` with the same value `-23`.
- comparison is to be performed on `int` and `unsigned int`, the common type is `unsigned int` as defined in the C Standard.
- The `int` is converted to an `unsigned int` with value `UINT_MAX - 23`, a very large number.
- The comparison is performed on the `unsigned int` values: `23` is the smaller value, the comparison evaluates to false.
- The `else` branch is evaluated, `no` is printed.

To make matters worse, if `c` had been defined as a `long`, the result would have depended on whether `long` and `int` have the same size or not.  On Windows, it would print `no`, whereas on 64 bit Linux, it would print `yes`.

Never mix signed and unsigned values in comparisons.  Enable compiler warnings to prevent this kind of mistake (`-Wall` or `-Weverything`).  You might as well make all these warnings fatal with `-Werror` to avoid this kind of ill-fated code entirely.

For a complete reference, read the following sections of the C Standard (C11) under **6.3 Conversions**:

- *integer promotions* are explained in **6.3.1.1 Boolean, characters, and integers**.
- *operand conversions* are detailed in **6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions**.

You can download the latest draft of the C11 Standard from the working group website: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Comment: Useful reference as a complement to this answer: https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/c/INT02-C.+Understand+integer+conversion+rules

Comment: And 6.3.1.1 for the *integer promotions*. [Here's a link](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) to the N1570 draft of the C11 standard.